# How to move the first letter of a word to the end in C++: Ch. 10 #16

Tags: c++

I'm trying to move the first letter of a word to the end, then adding "ay" to the end. This is apart of Ch. 10 programming challenge 16 in the C++ book with a grapefruit on the cover.

I have no idea where to start.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void toUpper(char *);
void reArrange(char *);
//string addAY(char);

//Consistent Variables
const int SIZE = 100;

int main() {

    //User input holder
    char input[SIZE];

    //Prompt
    cout << "Please enter a phrase: " << endl;
    cin.getline(input, SIZE);

    //Function calls



    //Print pig latin
    cout << "You entered: ";
    toUpper(input);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Transalted to pig latin: " << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void toUpper(char *input) {

    int i = 0;
    char c;
    while (input[i])
    {
        c = input[i];
        putchar(toupper(c));
        i++;
    }
}

void reArrange(char *input) {



}
```

Comment: Well, this is probably not the best place to start. There are plenty of beginner C++ tutorials out there. Give them a shot and when you get stuck on a specific problem, feel free to come back here for help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. Here is one:

```
std::string word = "hello";
word = word.substr(1, word.length() - 1) + word.front() + "ay";
std::cout << word;
```

Output:

```
ellohay
```

For a proper solution you also want to do some range checking.

Answer (score 0):

As @J.R. stated, there are many ways to do this.  I would use std::string rather than char*.

Here is one way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void reArrange(std::string& str);
void addAy(std::string &str);
//string addAY(char);

//Consistent Variables
const int SIZE = 100;

int main()
{

  //User input holder
  std::string input_line;
  //Prompt
  std::cout << "Please enter a phrase: " << endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, input_line);

  //Print pig latin
  std::cout << "You entered: " << input_line << endl;
  std::cout << "Transalted to pig latin: " << endl;

  reArrange(input_line);
  addAy(input_line);

  cout << input_line << ":\n";
  std::string wait_var;
  std::cin >> wait_var;
  return 0;
}

// pass by reference
void addAy(std::string& str) {
  str += "ay";
}

//pass by reference
void reArrange(std::string& str)
{
  char first_letter = str[0];
  str = str.substr(1, str.length()-1) + first_letter;
}
```